# Calling compiled code in another package

Tags: r

Consider the `lm.influence` function from the package `stats`.
I've written a slightly modified version of it (`wlm.influence`). 
But when calling it, I get:

```
Error in wlm.influence(fitg) : object 'C_influence' not found
```

How can I access this from outside `stats`? 
I tried the obvious solutions:

```
.Call("C_influence", mqr, do.coef, e)
.Call(stats:::C_influence, mqr, do.coef, e)
.Call(C_influence, mqr, do.coef, e,PACKAGE="stats")
```

to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C_influence` is an unexported object in the `stats` namespace, so it can be retrieved with `stats:::C_influence`. Your second solution should work, but you left out the last parameter: `tol`.